# Can a Raspberry RP2040 MCU design omit USB altogether?

Tags: microcontroller, rp2040

I've checked the [Hardware design with RP2040](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/hardware-design-with-rp2040.pdf) document and the [RP2040 datasheet](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/rp2040-datasheet.pdf), but it does not answer my question: is USB mandatory in a RP2040 custom design?

Could I just use a QSPI Flash, crystal oscillator and a voltage regulator and then just use the SWD pins to debug/write an .elf file to storage?

Comment: USB is just a peripheral. It is not required that you use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to use USB. The SWD pins (24, 25) can be used to load firmware into SRAM or external flash memory.

Strictly speaking, according to the documentation, you don't even need an external oscillator or external flash memory. The RP2040 has quite a bit of SRAM which can be used for data and code. SRAM is volatile though, so the applications are limited. Also it has an internal oscillator.
Of course an external clock can be necessary, depending what you want to do.

Comment: Yeah, technically you could load a program into ram over SWD on every startup and skip out on the flash chip.

Comment: Right, I clarified that it's not necessarily practical.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

---

*Pedantic note: You need a bit more, beginning with some conducting lines, for example a PCB, some passive components, ...*